# more button click and next buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

[image]

Hi Team,
I have website. I need to click on more button ( 3 dots in screenshot) and then once popup click on "Export to Excel"
//*[@id="OverflowButton_button0_account$button"] This is xpath retrieved from website. Once you click on this button a form opens which has Export to Excel button. for Export to Excel button doesnt has any inspect source. it doesnt has any id or name

That 3 dots named "more.."
Regards

Comment: Could you show us the url of the page?

Comment: sorry. cant paste link here. but do you have any solution that look in group of buttons and click on desired button.

Comment: Then provide HTML structure of that part! And also add what you have tried so far!

Comment: //*[@id="OverflowButton_button0_account$button"] This is xpath retrieved from website. Once you click on this button a form opens which has Export to Excel button. for Export to Excel button doesnt has any inspect source. it doesnt has any id or name.

Comment: In question not in comment! @NarendraSuryawanshi can't you just take screenshot or provide in text form that complete HTML structure?

Comment: @NarendraSuryawanshi you can vote my answer if you like my effort. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
driver=Webdriver.<>()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="OverflowButton_button0_account$button"]')click()

# You may need some delay here.

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Export to Excel')]").click()
```